# Angular application Build

Tags: javascript, angular

I tried to build an Angular application on my machine by installing node modules and I get the error as attached

This application totally works fine when installed on another machine. So its not a problem with the code. But please let me know how I can solve this
I just tried did
npm install
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng build
 where at the last build thing, I get this error
Let me know how to solve it[image]

Package.json file

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.6",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^0.7.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.39",
    "@types/ramda": "^0.26.9",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "pretty-quick": "^1.10.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.6",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "typescript": "3.1.6"
  }
```

And the errors are as such

```
 Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:215:42)    
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:69:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:55:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:86:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:17:28
    at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:65:54)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (C:\Project\UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:55:14)
```

Comment: Please include error text as text, not as a picture of text.

Comment: I did add the errors as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run command rm -rf node_modules/

clean catch by giving command npm clean cache -f

Please perform the following steps and let me know if its working.

```
npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.0
```

Comment: Hi Rahul,I tried deleting the nodemodules and installing it again,But still the issue is the same.Attached the image to the actual post in the starting

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json change the devkit builder.

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.6",
```

to

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.0",
```

Clear node modules before install again.